# Rendering form removes classes added by Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jsf, responsive-design

I am currently at a redesign process of a web application, where I have to integrate responsive design in an existing UI.

Therefore, I wanted to add `col-*` classes to certain html tags. Like for tables:

```
function addColstoTableCells() {
    $('table tr.formularClass td').addClass("col-6");
    $('table.formularTableClass tr td').addClass("col-6");
}
```

This successfully applies the `col-6` class to all required form tags. But when I am clicking on a checkbox, which renders the form like:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="ernst" value="#{dto.ernst}" disabled="#{!backingBean.sb.edit}">
                        <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" onevent="setFocus" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>Ernst</td>
```

the added `col-` classes get removed and the form is displayed without the `col-` width-style. Is there a way to make the classes added by Jquery persistent? The web application is huge and it would take hours to manually apply them to all `td` tags.

Comment: Forgive the ignorance, but where do `<h:` and `<f:` come from?

Comment: <h: and <f: both are standard components of the JSF framework, which allow you to use e.g. html tags within your jsp / facelets

Comment: Ok, I've added it as a tag.

Comment: nice of you, thanks!

Comment: TBH you might want to consider a redesign of the UI.  The fact that you're using **tables for layout** already makes it harder to refactor to a responsive design.

Comment: One option would be to apply (copy) the `col-6` css rules to `table tr.formularClass td` (etc) within the css itself, then there would be no need to apply via JS and get a FOUC (Flash Of Unstyled Content).

Comment: i can't consider as I am an interne and I was assigned to do that.. 
i've already tried that with sass, with just extending the col-6 class, but you are right, I just realised I missed something back then. Thank you!

Comment: you can (re) execute the javascript when the ajax event completes. Check Stackoverflow on how to do that

Comment: I will also have a look at this option! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was using CSS not JQuery to append the `col-*` style class.

If you are using Sass, simply extend your desired classes / elements:

```
table {
  tr.formularClass td, &.formularTableClass tr td{
      @extend .col-6;
      display: table-cell;
   }
}
```

If you are using CSS, just copy & paste the contents of the `col-*` style class into the class you want to extend.